# Search for a YouTube link in twitter feed?

Tags: php, twitter, youtube

I wonder if I can search for a tweets that shared a particular YouTube video. And sort out the users who got the most followers sharing the YouTube video. Only using their API and in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Twitter (and other URL shortening applications) encode the URL, you'll have to do the following:

1) Collect all your tweets with hyperlinks
2) Open the hyperlinks to see if they redirect to Youtube
3) Compile the ID's on the redirects
4) Use the Twitter API to do identify your followers

In short yes, but no.